# Xamarin Android: network_security_config.xml for debug only

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project (as a part of a Xamarin.Forms project) where I use network-security-config.xml to allow traffic to/from a test server using http.

I wonder if there is a way to exclude this from release build.

I found out two approaches, but none of them seem to apply to my situation:

- If I was using Android Studio, I could have two different files, in different folders, one for debug and one for release. I think this is not supported in Visual Studio/Xamarin.
- There is a directive in network_security_config.xml, "", but I think it only applies to CA certificates.

Any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Android project you can create your own Application class and extend the `Android.App.Application` class. This way you can enable/disable debugging of the app also.
The build will now that this is your manifest's `Application` node when you apply an `ApplicationAttribute` to it like so:

```cs
#if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable = true, NetworkSecurityConfig = "@xml/network_security_config")]
#else
    [Application(Debuggable = false)]
#endif
    public class MainApplication : Android.App.Application
    {
    }
```

Where `network_security_config` is your configuration file.